# How to determine initial TCP window size without sending a packet?

Tags: linux, tcp

I was thinking of writing a patch for Nmap that would make it more difficult to detect a port scanning attempt by setting the initial window size to one that the sender's operating system uses. Can I somehow find out which initial window size would be used if I tried to send a packet to, say, `8.8.8.8` over `wlan0`?

Comment: To whoever is downvoting this - could you please leave a comment on why you consider this post low quality?

Comment: How would this affect a port scanning attempt?

Comment: Right now it possible to detect a port scanning attempt when an unpopular window size is used. Take a look here: http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2015/q3/52

Comment: So the patch has already been written?

Comment: @EJP: right now it's only possible to set a specific value using this patch, but I wanted to have a go at implementing a mechanism that would detect which value would be most appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

The default should be 65536 bytes. Maybe this is what you are looking for:
/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max – Maximum TCP Receive Window.
/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max – Maximum TCP Send Window.

Comment: Sending a probe to 8.8.8.8 shows a default window size of 29200 on my host. Are you getting different results?

Comment: The default cannot possibly be more than 65535. You would need window scaling to be in effect for 65536 to be possible, and window scaling is off by default. There is in reality no initial window default at all: it is entirely system- and application-dependent

Comment: @EJP: my question is about Linux and how to query this specific system for the window. I noticed that it's different on loopback, so I assume that this also depends on the interface.

Comment: @d33tah That doesn't change anything. The application can set a large or small window size, and the operating system's default can change with releases, or by configuration.

Comment: @EJP: where can I read up on how applications can regulate the window size?

Comment: The initial receive window size is the size of the socket receive buffer, which can be changed via `setsockopt()`.

Comment: @EJP: that sounds like a possible answer. If you are confident about this, perhaps you could post it as one?

Comment: after linux kernel 3.x the initial window size max to 10 * mss, setsockopt does not work. you can google or read tcp implementation.@EJP